# computing ridge estimate manually in R, simple

Tags: r, regression, manual

I'm trying to learn about ridge regression, and I am using R. From what I understand the following should be the same `beta.r1` and `beta.r2` in the code below are the same

```
library(MASS)
n=50
v1=runif(n)
v2=v1+2
V=cbind(1,v1,v2)
w=3+v1+v2
I=diag(3)

lambda=2 #arbitrarily chosen

beta.r1=solve(t(V)%*%V+lambda*I)%*%t(V)%*%w

#Using library(MASS)
fit=lm.ridge(w~v1+v2,lambda=2, Inter=FALSE)
beta.r2=coef(fit)
#Shouldn't beta.r1 and beta.r2 be the same?
```

Comment: Chose n to be 50, sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: This is an interesting one. The actual `lm.ridge` code can be examined by entering `lm.ridge` at the command prompt. It is not terribly long.
You could then copy it, and modify it so that it prints out intermediate results and you could examine the differences. I will be looking at it more because I am interested in the problem too, but for now I will say that what it is doing does not look much like your formula at all, and among other things involves a svd of the input data.

Answer (score 1):

I think the variable scaling performed in the `lm.ridge` code (which you can access by typing `lm.ridge` into your R console) that likely cause differences. The code scales each variable by its root-mean-squared value:

```
Xscale <- drop(rep(1/n, n) %*% X^2)^0.5
X <- X/rep(Xscale, rep(n, p))
```

Your code does not perform any variable scaling.

The variable scaling is hinted at on the `?lm.ridge` help page in the description of what is returned by `lm.ridge`:

> scales: scalings used on the X matrix.

Therefore you can access the scaling used by `lm.ridge`:

```
fit$scales
#        v1        v2 
# 0.2650311 0.2650311
```